# How do I place an image created in Open Gl ES into a UIView for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, tic-tac-toe

I want to create a tic tac toe game for iOS using Swift. I created the tic tac toe board using OpenGL ES 2.0. However the board fills the whole screen. I want to place the board into a view, so then I can center the view making the board centered for all devices. How do I place my object I created in OpenGL ES into a UIView?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, how are you currently displaying your Open GL content to the user? You should either be using a `GLKViewController`, `GLKView` or `CAEAGLayer`. All of these you can layout easily.

Comment: Yea I was using GLKViewController and GLKView. I don't know what I was thinking, it is very easy to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use view controller containment. Add your `GLKViewController` as a child view controller to a `UIViewController` and center its view.